# How can you block or filter IP addresses on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, ip, rack

Is there a way to implement IP filtering or IP access rules much like I would with nginx/apache to restrict or block certain IPs on Heroku?

**Note:** I know this can be done from within my application (Rails 3.2) very easily but I don't think this is the most efficient use of my resources on Heroku.  Also, a Rack based solution would be better than implementing the filtering in Rails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I added ['rack-block'](https://github.com/udzura/rack-block) as Rack middleware. In config/initializers, add a new file:

```
YourApp::Application.configure do

  config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Block) do  
    # Add your rules with the rack-block syntax in here
  end

end
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm kinda concerned with my googling skills now.

Comment: Is there a way to block centain addresses before the request hit the dyno?

Comment: How can I block all IP addresses except for one IP I want to allow? To me it seems with rack-block I have to list ALL IP addresses I want to block :(

Comment: @morgler: check out my answer below. `rack-attack` has a whitelist feature - https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack

Comment: Is it possible to block IPs at a 'server' level, so that we don't have to muck around with our app?

Comment: If you want to block requests before they hit the dyno's you need to use a Web Application Firewall - there's one in the Heroku Addons Marketplace - https://elements.heroku.com/addons/expeditedwaf

Answer (score 19):

You should check out [rack-attack](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack). Looks like it does the same as rack-block, but is much more widely used and updated frequently. To block a specific IP you can do this:

```
# Block requests from 1.2.3.4
Rack::Attack.blacklist('block 1.2.3.4') do |req|
  # Requests are blocked if the return value is truthy
  '1.2.3.4' == req.ip
end
```

Comment: Can I block an IP range? i.e 1.2.3.*?

Comment: @Stefanos.Ioannou to block the value you just need to make sure the block you pass to `Rack::Attack.blacklist` returns true. You could do something like this:

`(0..255).map{ |val| '1.2.3.' + val.to_s }.include?(req.ip)`

Comment: @Phil I'm being pedantic about a contrived example, but... ;) You'd probably be better off with `starts_with?('1.2.3')` there - building an array of 256 strings, then checking if the ip is amongst those might not be massive computationally, but possibly not something you want to do on every request if not necessary.