# Block IPs on heroku

Tags: heroku

I haven't found this any where in heroku's documentation or on google. Typically this is done in the host file. Does anyone have any idea how to block an ip on heroku?

Comment: Coming in (to your site) or going out (from your site)?  Also, what are you trying to accomplish? There may be a better way than IP blocking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you block or filter IP addresses on Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136260/how-can-you-block-or-filter-ip-addresses-on-heroku)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heroku doesn't have a firewall that you can use to block IPs, so you would have to either block it at the application level, or you would have to put a proxy of some sort in front of your application that you can use to block the IP. One common one people use is [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), which has support for blocking individual IPs, rate limiting IPs, etc.

If you want to stick with blocking at the application level, and are using Ruby on Rails, this question and answer which might give you what you're looking for: [How can you block or filter IP addresses on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136260/how-can-you-block-or-filter-ip-addresses-on-heroku)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the link in this answer is a RoR solution only?

Comment: @GreenAsJade, you're right. I've edited my answer to be more generic.

Comment: If you are using Django https://gitlab.com/tmkn/django-basic-auth-ip-whitelist is an option

Comment: How would you use CloudFlare to block IP addresses, if you have a custom domain linked on Heroku? The latter means that Heroku is using DNS for your domain, so you can't tick the "orange cloud" on Cloudflare, and essentially the requests will bypass CloudFlare, not filtering etc.

Answer (score 10):

Since this was first answered, Heroku has added a Web Application Firewall in their AddOn Marketplace: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/expeditedwaf

It can block inbound requests by IP, UserAgent, Referrer, Country, etc.

Comment: Nice addon. Worked for me!

Comment: Is there any new add-on that is free?