# Spring Security Getting the client IP without using headers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

My application sits behind a caching server that acts as a proxy. I'd like to limit access to the application so that it can only be accessed via the proxy. I first tried using a RemoteAddrFilter, however this filters based on the X-Forwarded-For header which is the IP address of the user connecting to the proxy, not the IP address of the proxy (This header is forwarded instead of being overwritten by the proxy). I decided to write my own filter based off of the RemoteAddrFilter:

```
public class IpFilter extends RequestFilter {

@Override
protected Log getLogger() {
    return null;
}

private void sendErrorWhenNotHttp(ServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write(sm.getString("http.403"));
    response.getWriter().flush();
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (/*check IP*/) {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    } else if (servletResponse instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
        ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).sendError(denyStatus);
    } else {
        sendErrorWhenNotHttp(servletResponse);
    }
}
}
```

This gives me much more control over what can be accessed, however I'm unsure what to put into this *if* statement.

From what I can tell, given the parameters exposed here, the only accessible IP addresses are via headers, which do not represent the IP address of the proxy.

How can I get the IP address of the proxy?

Comment: This should never been processed at the application level! Of course, you should limit the allowed accesses to your application, but it is a not a programming task but an administrative one. And the sysadmin of the server hosting the application can use a filter (iptables, ipfw, ipfilter, etc.) to do it by simple configuration. Anyway, in corporate datacenters the routing rules prevent any accesses to the application server except through their dedicated proxies. That is the reason why Spring Security does its best to let the application know the client IP instead of the proxy IP.

Comment: @SergeBallesta While that makes sense, I'm using an infrastructure-as-a-service platform so I have very limited control over the environment the application is running in. This means none of the usual tools like iptables or ufw.

Edit: Here's another post, for a different language. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185291/block-ips-on-heroku/13006531

Based on the answer, it seems the only solution to isolate communication is at the application level.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai These headers are set to the user's IP address by the proxy, so I'm unsure how the filter would make a difference

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Unfortunately that's still not the proxy's IP address

Comment: Let me take a look at the contents of X-FORWARDED-FOR

Comment: Even if I place the filter before anything else in the chain, X-FORWARD-FOR and request.getRemoteAddr do not contain the proxy's IP

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai So the only way to get the proxy server's IP is if it appends itself to this header? Even if I did use the header to identify the proxy server, couldn't one set this header manually to include that IP, which would defeat the purpose of doing this in the first place.

Comment: It can surely be configured to send this in the header (It's nginx), but that would defeat the point of checking the IP at all because the header could easily be added by a bad actor trying to impersonate the proxy server.

Comment: Yes, which is why the title of this posts asks for a way to get the IP address without relying on the headers